# What does mean $\mathbb E[u(X_{\tau+t})\mid \mathcal F_{\tau+}]=\mathbb E[u(X_{\tau+t})\mid X_{\tau}]$ on $\{\tau<\infty \}$?

Tags: probability

What does mean $$\mathbb E[u(X_{\tau+t})\mid \mathcal F_{\tau+}]=\mathbb E[u(X_{\tau+t})\mid X_{\tau}]\quad \text{on}\quad \{\tau<\infty \} \ \ ?$$

Does it mean that

$$\mathbb E\left[u(X_{\tau+t})\mid \mathcal F_{\tau+}\Big | \ \tau <\infty \right]=\mathbb E\left[u(X_{\tau+t})\mid X_{\tau}\Big|\ \tau<\infty \right] \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, conditional expectations are random variables. $X=Y$ on $A$ simply means $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ for $\omega \in A$. However conditional expectations are only defined up to null sets, so we should say 'for almost all $\omega$ with $\tau (\omega) < \infty$.